# What is a neat way to delete a stale amavisd pid_file on first boot after panic or power failure?

Tags: email, server.app, smtp

Lion Mail Server component postfix/smtp 100% reproducible blocks inbound smtp mail delivery on first boot after a panic or power failure.

Error messages from mail.log are like:

```
postfix/smtp[45785]: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused
postfix/smtp[45785]: 2F7131F9A97: to=<user@host.tld>, relay=none, delay=76041, delays=76040/0.36/0.05/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
postfix/error[45790]: 550D61F9A99: to=<user@host.tld>, relay=none, delay=76040, delays=76040/0.39/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
postfix/postscreen[45872]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from [100.200.100.159]:65392: 450 4.3.2 Service currently unavailable; from=<user2@host2.tld>, to=<user@host.tld>, proto=ESMTP, helo=<host.domain.tld>
/usr/libexec/postfix/greylist.pl[45885]: Temporary message rejection to: <user@host.tld> from: <user2@host2.tld> sent from: [100.200.100.159] for: 60 seconds due to greylisting
postfix/smtpd[45879]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from host.domain.tld[100.200.100.159]: 450 4.7.1 <user@host.tld>: Recipient address rejected: Service is unavailable; from=<user2@domain2.tld> to=<user@domain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<host.domain.tld>
```

The issue seems to be related to the **amavis** content filter due to the connection to port number 10024 and amavisd being configured on that port. Amavis.log:

```
/usr/bin/amavisd[236]: (!)Net::Server: 2012/07/25-13:38:49 Pid_file already exists for running process (88)... aborting\n\n  at line 277 in file /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/Net/Server.pm
...
/usr/bin/amavisd[236]: Net::Server: 2012/07/25-13:38:49 Server closing!
...repeating roughly every 10 seconds...
```

The **workaround** is to delete `/var/amavis/amavisd.pid` or reboot the machine. After the second boot the inbound smtp mail delivery is no longer stuck.

The issue seems to be **related to** https://serverfault.com/questions/138690/amavisd-net-server-pid-file-already-exists-after-system-crash-and-startup

**How to permanently fix** Apple Mail Server to accept smtp inbound messages on first boot, by removing the left over amavis pid_file from the previous unclean shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Reconfigure amavisd

So that its pid file will be erased upon boot. Thus change the default pid file location from `/var/amavis/amavisd.pid` to [a folder that is empty on every boot](https://serverfault.com/a/480912/75679). For example `/private/var/run`.

Note: Lion runs amavisd as user `_amavisd`. To allow user `_amavisd` to write anything in `/private/var/run` the `_amavisd` user needs to be added to group `daemon`. Otherwise amavis errors out with:

> Couldn't open pid file "/private/var/run/amavisd.pid" [Permission
> denied]

```
$ sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a _amavisd -t user daemon
$ sudo nano /etc/amavisd.conf
# $pid_file = "$MYHOME/var/amavisd.pid";   # -P
$pid_file = '/private/var/run/amavisd.pid';
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.amavis.amavisd.plist;sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.amavis.amavisd.plist
```

---

## Option 2: Create a launchd item

That runs on boot (system startup before amavisd is started) executing the command to test that /var/amavis/amavisd.pid exists and then delete it:

```
if test -f /var/amavis/amavisd.pid; then rm /var/amavis/amavisd.pid
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.amavis.amavisd_delete_pid</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>if</string>
        <string>test</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/var/amavis/amavisd.pid;</string>
        <string>then</string>
        <string>rm</string>
        <string>/var/amavis/amavisd.pid</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```